# NLTK not getting imported in VS Code

Tags: python, import, nlp, nltk

I have just started learning NLP and for that purpose I installed nltk package using `pip install nltk` in the cmd terminal of VS Code. After I installed it, I tried importing it in the command line itself and I was successful but in the main window where we write the code, I tried `from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize` but it showed the following error:

[image]

then I tried simply `import nltk` but that too didn't work, and it showed the following error:

[image]

I also tried restarting VS Code, but it was all in vain. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does the code work or is it just Pylance warnings?

Comment: No. The code doesn't work too. It shows `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nltk'`